# How to use MongoDB find without a hexadecimal _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, binary, hex

I am having a lot of trouble finding a record in my database with the `_id: "AAE45/0RQfm/VUrywfb1Gw=="` 
(eg. `db.collection.find( {_id: new BinData(3, "AAE45/0RQfm/VUrywfb1Gw==") })` ).

It works fine using a `BinData` converter in the mongo console, but refuses to work from inside a javascript file (I am using node.js) even though I have installed the BinData npm and "required" it.

I have also tried the `Binary()` function, but it keeps telling me it needs to be hexadecimal or 12-byte binary or something. `.hex, .str` and `.toString()` don't work either. 
I found this somewhere:

```
{"$binary": "AAE45/0RQfm/VUrywfb1Gw==", "$type": "03"}
```

which looks promising, but I have no idea how to implement it.

I hope this makes sense. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated, if anyone has any insight on what process I should follow (eg: convert to binary, then hex, then use ...) that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to convert the base64 string to a byte array, then use [`Binary`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/binary.html) to create the corresponding mongodb object. Here's some working sample code that inserts a document with the given id in a mongodb collection:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Binary = require('mongodb').Binary;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/example", function (err, db) {
    if (err) { return console.dir(err); }
    var collection = db.collection('test');
    // decode the base64 string into a buffer
    var buf = new Buffer("AAE45/0RQfm/VUrywfb1Gw==", 'base64');

    // create a mongo 'binary' object w/ subtype 3
    var uuid = new Binary(buf, 3);
    var doc1 = { 'hello': 'foo bar', '_id' : uuid };
    collection.insert(doc1, { w: 1 }, function (err, result) { });
});
```

You might want to ensure you really want to use subtype 3, because it's the *old* UUID type.